# Accessing audio input while loading a project from file://

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder to know if it is possible to somehow prevent Chrome from blocking my project audio input because I'm not loading it from a local host but from file://... a.k.a. my HDD.

I'm asking about this because I've understood that when the script is non-server but loaded from file:// Chrome automatically blocks it and it can't reach the asking-for-mic-usage-permission step.

I'm playing around with annyang at the moment, if someone knows how to enable the described above, please share with me, as I still have no idea of how php, mysql and others manage to establish a local host environment.

Comment: Are you on a mac/linux system? the simplest solution is probably to `cd` into the project folder and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. This will create a server running at localhost:8000 that serves your project's files. This will get around the security restrictions for file:// .

Comment: oh, excuse me, I forgot to mention... I'm running windows 8.1

Comment: Ok, I've installed python, I went to D:/..../...the-directory-of-my-project and I tried python -m SimpleHTTPServer and run python -m SimpleHTTPServer but none of both did the job.